# How does one automatically generate a hyperlink for a cell containing a path?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm familiar with the `HYPERLINK` formula in Google Sheets to create links in a column, using a value in separate column as seen in this screenshot in row #2.

[image]

I want the user to have the ability to enter a path and have a link, using a predefined domain, automatically generated, as shown in A3, *without* having to use the "INSERT" -> "Insert link" command.  This way if they insert new rows, and add a path to a new cell, the link will automatically generate. And if they update the path in the cell, the link updates accordingly. I'm hoping to set this up to also save space because an extra column doesn't have to be added to the sheet.

I tried conditional formatting, but wasn't able to accomplish my goal.

Comment: How do you expect that Google Sheets will know how to convert that path on a URL? Are the URL stored somewhere? Have already know how to use macros and Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Rubén, That's the question I'm asking.  The `Hyperlink` formula provides this functionality, I just want to be able to set the value of a cell to be the path, but set the rendering of the cell to show the hyperlink.  In this fashion if the user hovers over the link, they can click the link that appears, but if they hit ENTER on the keyboard or double click the cell, they can edit the value.  I just don't know if there is a feature in Google Sheets that provides this level of customization to how cells are rendered.

Comment: Here is the formula I used on the cell B1, `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.somedomain.com",A1),"LINK")`.  I want to be able to apply this formula to a cell and have it render the link in the same cell if that's even possible.

Comment: You probably need a Google Apps Script for that, i.e. some JavaScript programming work - your [so] profile indicates that you'd manage.

Comment: @Glorfindel I figured the solution may go along those lines. I began looking at it, but haven't had a chance to really get familiar with it.  If I am able to come to a solution, I'll post it.